# Org-mode file hyperlinks always use doc-view, can't force it to use external pdf viewer

Tags: org-mode, pdf, docview

I am using Emacs 25.1 run with `emacs -Q` and Org mode version 8.2.10. This problem persists in my [customized Emacs](https://github.com/igorpere/emacs-config) with Org mode version 8.3.6.

I am attempting to open hyperlinks of the form

```
[[file:documenterino.pdf][documenterino]]
```

using the external default pdf viewer, evince.
When I create the above link, it turns into a blue, underlined `documenterino`. If I use `C-c C-o`, `C-u C-c C-o`, or `C-u C-u C-c C-o` on it, I get the same result every time: the pdf opens in a new `docview` buffer in emacs, when I want it to open outside emacs in evince.

I tried changing `file:` to `file+sys:`, and `~/documents/documenterino.pdf` instead of `documenterino.pdf`, but there is no change.

LMouse, RMouse, and MMouse also open in doc-view regardless of changes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed the problem by using `M-x customize-variable org-file-apps` and adding a cons-cell with `Extension: \.pdf\'` and `Command: evince %s` at the top.

[image: emacs customize screen]

Oddly enough, links starting with `file+sys:` still open in emacs doc-view, while links starting with `file:` open in evince (regadless of absolute or relative path). But I don't care because there's no autocompletion for `file+sys:` anyway.

Answer (score 5):

I added 
`(add-to-list 'org-file-apps '("pdf" . "evince %s"))`
to my init-file.  Now `C-c C-o` opens any PDF in evince and `C-u C-u C-c C-o` opens them in `doc-view`.

Comment: Same behaviour persists.

Comment: Have you evaluated the form with `C-x C-e` or restarted Emacs?

Comment: Yes. I've seen this advice in a bunch of other places too, often it comes with a lot of backslashes and dots in various places (eg `'("\\.pdf\\" . "evince \\%s\\"")` . Never does anything, always defaults to doc-view.

Even tried using this command in `emacs -Q` (after `('require org)`, since it won't run otherwise) and nothing changes.